# How to have a feature unlocked after you get a certain score

Tags: ios, objective-c

ok, so i want to have a new character unlocked when you get a certain score in the game. i have my high-score mechanism setup so that an integer called "score number" recognizes the score at the end of the game (based off of a timer system) and sets it as the new high-score (assuming you got a better score). and then it will reset the integer back to 0. the problem here is that i can't say if: the integer reads over lets say 30, then unlock this feature, because it resets to 0. so my question is: is there another way to unlock this feature in the game without using this method. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have two different score values, currentScore and highScore.

Save highScore to user NSUserDefaults.

At the end of each round, compare the new score to the high score. If the new score is higher, save it to the high score NSUserDefaults key.

Then use highScore to determine what levels are unlocked.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you can't just do it this way before you reset your int back to 0:

```
if (scorenumber == 30) {
    // unlock new level
} else if (scorenumber == 100) {
    // unlock another level
}
```

Comment: This won't work based on what he wrote. The score resets to 0, so you will pass `scorenumber` multiple times. In addition, you are assuming his scoring is +1 every time. This may not be the case. BTW, yes he says timer based, but there is nothing that says you may get getter "points" from some action/event.

Comment: In that case, can't he use his `highscore` int instead of `scorenumber` for the if statement unlocks?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can handle this. You can use bit flag or specific flag to indicate if something is unlocked.

So, for example, you may do something like

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, Unlockable) {
    UnlockableA = 1,
    UnlockableB = 2,
};

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger unlockables;

// Code for checking score and unlockables.
// Hardcoding these values is bad, but just doing this for convenience now
if (self.scorenumber >= 30) {
    if (self.unlockables & UnlockableA) {
        // Unlock A
        self.unlockables |= UnlockableA;
    }
}

// Note this is not an else if, so you can award it in cases 
// if you had score numbers incrementing at arbitrary values
if (self.scorenumber >= 100) {
    if (self.unlockables & UnlockableB) {
        // Unlock B
        self.unlockables |= UnlockableB;
    }
}
```

Code is not tested for compilation, accuracy, etc.

You have to make sure to persist `unlockables`, which also implies reading it in at start.

If you went the specific variable route, you'd do something like:

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) BOOL unlockedA;
```

You can figure out the rest from here.

Another option would be to use an `NSDictionary` to hold the `BOOL` (as an `NSNumber`).

There are other ways of doing it, but these are the low hanging fruit methods.

Comment: lets say i wanted to unhide a button as the feature for the game. where would i put the code in for that in this example?